# Question regarding Schedule 13D

Tags: united-states, accounting, sec

I have very limited accounting experience, and I'm looking at the publicly traded firm, QC Holding, Inc. I want to know more about controlling interest in the firm, so I was looking at their SC 13Ds on EDGAR. I'm looking at two in particular, that were filled by the same individual. One reported the individual owned 6.3% of the firms shares, while the other reported the individual owned 7.5%. Neither filling was an amendment. Does this mean the individual now owns 13.8% of the firm's shares, or is the later 7.5% number the individual's current ownership?

Answer (score 1):

my guess is the number is their current holdings, not recent acquisition. ie you don't add them together, just take the latest filing.